# How to efficiently fetching data from rest api if data is not present or svelte-type store id data has already been fetched using Svelte / Sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper

When using Svelte/Sapper as framework, is there a straight way to fetch data from a rest api on initial server side render of a route eg. `/my-page` and store it, or alternatively fetch the data from a rest api on the client-side when navigating from another page to `/my-page` and store it, and on subsequent route changes to `my-page` get stored data using svelte-type store instead of fetching it again.

Seems like a trivial thing, but since stores are not intended to be used during server side renders, I haven't figured out a efficient / best practise way of doing this.

Comment: IMHO is alright to use a simple svelte-store for this task.

Comment: Svelte stores would also be my preferred way of handling the data, but the question is how to avoid fetching the data if already fetched oas described in the above scenario. Could you elaborate and show a code example?

Comment: What do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the data from a rest api I prefer using the onMount and a for each loop to get all the elements inside the object that the api returns. You can store those objects in an array in /mypage.